# Creating a method in c++

Tags: c++, function, methods

I'm trying to create a method in c++, where, when implemented would look like

```
pointA.distanceTo(pointB)
```

However, I'm having trouble trying to incorporate "pointA" into the method. Currently, my code for the method looks like this:

```
double Point::distanceTo(Point p1)
{
    double xDist=getxCoord()-???;
    double yDist=getyCoord()-???;
    return sqrt(xDist*xDist-yDist*yDist);
}
```

I know that the getxCoord() and getyCoord() methods will only get the object inside the parenthesis of distanceTo(Point p1).

But I have no clue how to get the object info from pointA in "pointA.distanceTo(pointB)".

Comment: ??? = `p1.getxCoord()` and ??? = `p1.getyCoord()`

Comment: Why did you use `getxCoord()` to get the x coordinate of the `pointA`? If a member function is defined in class `Point`, wouldn't its coordinates be directly accessible by the member function?

Comment: @ShauryaChats What makes you assume that it's stored as x and y coordinates directly w.r.t. the origin and not as, say, distance from some other reference point, so that it has to be calculated?

Comment: @legends2k I get your point.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the `getxCoord()` and `getyCoord()` methods will only get the object inside the parenthesis of `distanceTo(Point p1)`.

No! When you do `pointA.distanceTo(pointB);`, the argument `pointB` becomes the parameter `p1` in `pointA`'s `distanceTo` method (not the other way around). Thus

```
double Point::distanceTo(Point p1)
{
    double xDist = getxCoord()- p1.getxCoord();
    double yDist = getyCoord()- p1.getyCoord();
    return sqrt(xDist * xDist - yDist * yDist);
}
```

should work; here the first `getxCoord()` would operate on `pointA` (or `this` pointer) and the next would operate on `pointB`.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the getxCoord() and getyCoord() methods will only get the object inside the parenthesis of distanceTo(Point p1).

Actually you have it exactly backwards. Those two calls will get the values for *this object*, or PointA, also known simply as `this`. To get the details from `p1`, you have to call methods on it:

```
double xDist = this->getxCoord() - p1.getxCoord();
double yDist = this->getyCoord() - p1.getyCoord();
```

The `this` is implicit though, you don't need it. The above is equivalent to:

```
double xDist = getxCoord() - p1.getxCoord();
double yDist = getyCoord() - p1.getyCoord();
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined the function `distanceTo()` as a **member function** of class `Point`, and if you are invoking the function from `pointA`, automatically all the data members of `pointA` are accessible to this function.

Hence, you could call `getxCoord()` and `getyCoord()` for `pointB` and directly access the `X` and `Y` coordinates of `pointA` calling `getxCoord()` and `getyCoord()`.

Code:

```
double Point::distanceTo(Point p1)
{
    double xDist=getxCoord()-p1.getxCoord();
    double yDist=getyCoord()-p1.getyCoord();
    return sqrt(xDist*xDist-yDist*yDist);
}
```